# Error when trying to use the subcaption package

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

When I try to use the `subcaption` package (`\usepackage{subcaption}`), I get some errors. However, using the `subfigure` package (`\usepackage{subfigure}`), the compilation is successful with no errors. I cannot figure out what is wrong...

here is a code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{changepage}
%\usepackage{notoccite}

%a useful package if you write url addresses:
%\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]     
\centering
\subfigure[]
{
\label{fig: Image1} 
\includegraphics[width=76mm,height=60mm]{CordicStruc.pdf}
}
\subfigure[]
{
\label{fig: Image2} 
\includegraphics[width=76mm,height=60mm]{Diagram1.pdf}
}

\caption{\textbf{(a) Block diagram of floating-
point CORDIC co-processor architecture.} \textbf{(b) Pre-Process module in CORDIC co-processor.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that they are different packages, and that they do not work in the same way. The `subfigure` package defines a `\subfigure` command that is used to create subfigures, as in

```
\subfigure{\includegraphics{image}}
```

`subcaption` does *not* define such a command, but it does define a `subfigure` *environment*, used as

```
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
 \includegraphics{image}
 \caption{...}
\end{subfigure}
```

It also defines a `\subcaptionbox` command, that you can use.

Here is your code adapted to the `subcaption` package. I added examples for both the `subfigure` environment and `\subcaptionbox` command.

Note that the `demo` option to `graphicx` replaces the images with black rectangles, remove it for your own document.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]     
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=76mm,height=60mm]{CordicStruc.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig: Image1} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=76mm,height=60mm]{Diagram1.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig: Image1} 
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\textbf{(a) Block diagram of floating-
point CORDIC co-processor architecture.} \textbf{(b) Pre-Process module in CORDIC co-processor.}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htb]     
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=76mm,height=60mm]{CordicStruc.pdf}}
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=76mm,height=60mm]{Diagram1.pdf}}
\caption{\textbf{(a) Block diagram of floating-
point CORDIC co-processor architecture.} \textbf{(b) Pre-Process module in CORDIC co-processor.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```