# Errors and alignment of subfigures

Tags: errors, subfloats

I want to put two pictures side by side in a two-column conference paper. The LaTeX code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
% Add the compsoc option for Computer Society conferences.
% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.eps}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
   \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
%
% paper title
% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{0000}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}

% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{0000}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfig}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{pic/interest.png}
  \label{packet:interest}
\end{subfig}
\begin{subfig}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{pic/data.png}
  \label{packet:data}
\end{subfig}
\caption{CPI packet structure}
\label{packet}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I used a `.cls`file `IEEEtran.cls`‎:

```
www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls‎
```

I got the following errors:

```
There's no line here to end.
Missing number, treated as zero
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

there are two unexpected `.5` besides the subfigures and these 2 subfigures are aligned on the bottom, but I hope to align them 
on the top.

How to modify the code?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Can you create a complete example, i.e. one including a `documentclass` and preamble with only the necessary packages, ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: I guess you're the `subfigure` package. That is deprecated, `subfig` or `subcaption` is recommended instead. Further, that package (`subfigure`) does not define a `subfigure` *environment*, that would probably be why your code doesn't work properly. The `subcaption` package however, does define that environment, and your code snippet works fine if I use that. Final edit: somewhat related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129953/error-when-trying-to-use-the-subcaption-package/

Comment: @Torbjørn T. so, how to modify my code?

Comment: Are you using the `subfigure` package? It may work if you just replace it with `subcaption`, but without a complete example I cannot know for sure. (In general, *always* create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), it makes it a lot easier for those trying to help.)

Comment: I have updated my question, is it OK now? thanks

Comment: Did you try removing the {.5\textwidth} from the subfigure environment?

Comment: Ah, I remove it and the .5 disappear, but how to align these 2 pics on the top but not on the bottom? thanks

Comment: You could try \begin{figure}[t].

Comment: \begin{figure}[t] doesn't work. BTW, there are still errors alarm after removing the {.5\textwidth}, although the resulted pdf is fine.

Comment: user1944257 -- I just used your documentclass[conference] {IEEEtran} setting and the output is what I have shown, without errors.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing incompatible syntaxes. With the `subfigure` package you have a `\subfig` command and not a `subfig` environment.

However, calling `\begin{subfig}` executes `\subfig` which gets confused because it doesn't expect a length as argument.

The environment form with a stated length is available with the `subcaption` package, but the environment is called `subfigure`.

Here is a compiling code. Note that I loaded the package `graphicx` with the option `demo` just to show black blotches instead of the (unavailable) pictures. In the options for the pictures I added a `height=` statement in order to have them of different height; you don't need this statement, of course.

Recall also that the paper is typeset in two column format, so you have two choices:

1. Use the `figure` environment and express the width as a fraction of `\columnwidth`
2. Use the `figure*` environment and express the width as a fraction of `\textwidth`.

I used the first form; the `lipsum` package is just to fill the pages with nonsense text.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
% Add the compsoc option for Computer Society conferences.
% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{subcaption}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%
% paper title
% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{0000}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}



% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{0000}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,height=3cm]{pic/interest.png}
\end{subfigure}% <--- This is important!!!!
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,height=4cm]{pic/data.png}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{CPI packet structure}
\label{packet}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{a} x
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You resulted pdf is just what I want. I copied your codes between `\begin{figure} and \end{figure}` to my latex codes, but the result is not good. There are even more errors and the resulted figures in the pdf is in a mess.

Comment: @user1944267 Did you change `\usepackage{subfigure}` into `\usepackage{subcaption}`?

Comment: @egreg The `subfigure` environment (offered by the `subcaption` package) is in fact a `minipage` with the opportunity to typeset a sub-caption, but there is no sub-caption here. So why not take a `minipage` which does not require any of the sub-figure packages at all?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Using `subfigure` allows to easily add a subcaption without any other change.

Comment: I  change \usepackage{subfigure} into \usepackage{subcaption}. but it shows that there is no subcaption. but it prompts: File `subcaption.sty' not found. Then I downloaded subcaption.sty and put it in the same folder as my tex doc. Then the error is "subcaption: `caption' package not loadedSee the subcaption package documentation for explanation.". how to deal with this?

Comment: @user1944267 You have an outdated TeX distribution. If you don't need subcaptions, forget about this and use the `minipage` environment instead of `subfigure`: just change `\begin{subfigure}` into `\begin{minipage}` and the same for `\end`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result: putting pics top-border alignment of two-column format.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
 \usepackage[inner=0.75in,outer=0.65in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-2]
 \begin{figure}[!hbt]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth,height=4cm]{pic/interest.png}
 \label{fig:sub1}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}
 \centering
 \raisebox{1cm}\includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth,height=3cm]{pic/data.png}
 \label{fig:sub2}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{CPI packet structure}
 \label{packet}
 \end{figure}
 \lipsum[1-10]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no, I dont expect this. I jsut want to make the two subfigures' top border aligned.

Comment: I think I get it. You have different size of pic.  The simplest way is to use \raisebox{xxmm}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}. Or use  subcaption package.

Comment: can you show me an example? how to use raisebox? thx!

Comment: This is your example. I tried. \begin{subfigure}
\centering
\raisebox{2mm}{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{pic/data.png}}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}